# Weird Transparent Frame Reaction when button clicked

Tags: java, swing

i have this program that shows products for sale, the product frame is translucent as you can see,

product frame:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAG6A.png]

when i click the details button it changes the image to the description and changes the text in the details button to image, to switch back to the image, but this happens..

product frame after:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKiFJ.png]

images of buttons from around the parent frame and in the frame are duplicated and added to the frame in some strange effect, the more times i press the button the more they appear.

ive tried to revalidate the frame and repaint it but to no avail. any suggestions?

this is my detail button action listener

```
/**
* action listener for the detail buttons in the product frames
*/
 
 class MyActionListenerDetails implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        Component found;
        
        Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < detailsBTNS.length; i++){
            
            found = (Component) detailsBTNS[i];
            
            if(c.getParent().equals(found.getParent())){
                
                if(detailsBTNS[i].getText().matches("DETAILS")){
                    
                    try {

                        productName = String.valueOf(productIdentityLabels[i].getText());
                        Object[] details = data.getProductDetails(productName, category);

                        code = String.valueOf(details[0]);
                        String description = String.valueOf(details[1]);
                        String productWeight = String.valueOf(details[2]);

                        productImagesLabels[i].setIcon(null);
                        productImagesLabels[i].setBackground(Color.red);
                        productImagesLabels[i].setText("<html>Code: '" + code + "'<br/>Description: '" + description + "'<br/>Weight: '" + productWeight + "'<br/></html>");

                        detailsBTNS[i].setText("IMAGE");
                        detailsBTNS[i].revalidate();
                        productImagesLabels[i].revalidate();
                        c.getParent().revalidate();

                    } catch (SQLException ex) {

                        Logger.getLogger(ShopFront.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    
                }else{
                    
                    try {
                        
                        productName = String.valueOf(productIdentityLabels[i].getText());
                        
                        ImageIcon findImage = new ImageIcon(imageFolder + category + "\\" + data.getProductImage(productName, category));
                        
                        productImagesLabels[i].setText("");
                        
                        productImagesLabels[i].setIcon(changePicSize(findImage, productImagesLabels[i]));
                        
                        detailsBTNS[i].setText("DETAILS");
                        
                        detailsBTNS[i].revalidate();
                        productImagesLabels[i].revalidate();
                        
                        
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        
                        Logger.getLogger(ShopFront.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code please?

Comment: When swapping panels you should use a `CardLayout`. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). When you have painting artifacts it is usually because you override a painting method and don't invoke "super" on the painting method your override to make sure the background is cleared.

Comment: code added, there are 6 product frames (identical) all their buttons and labels as well as the frames are part of their own array.. so thisArray[1] is on the same product as thatArray[1],

Comment: ill have to have a look at the card layout, ok ill give the paint method ago, ill come back to you , thanks

Comment: *ok ill give the paint method ago* - that is not what I suggested. If are not doing custom painting, then you don't need to worry. My comment was about IF you were doing custom painting.

Comment: @camickr yes sorry it was late, i was exhausted.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you, i really need to structure my questions better

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.
The `JFrame` in question was not the issue, it was the `JPanel` it was set in.

Calling this fixed the issue.

```
productPanels[i].getParent().repaint();
```